# Application pool is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool

Tags: asp.net

This website is hosted shared hosting 'Windows Server 2012', The website stopped working and give me general "Service Unavailable" error. I contacted the support they said `"Currently, your site is working fine. You have availed additional Application pool memory for your site. When the application memory allocated to the site reaches to the maximum limit your site will stop. In this case, you will need to check the script/code of your VPS. We have attached logs for this matter along with this response."`, Now the website is going down again and again. Also, I checked the website files and found many files are with a strange name that I do not have any idea about them!!. Please help me to solve this problem.

This is what the logs file said:

```
Application pool 'sceryemen.com v4.0 (Classic)' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
Date:          4/8/2014 2:22:04 AM
Event ID:      1309
Task Category: Web Event
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Accu17.denver.wehostwebsites.com
Description:
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 4/8/2014 2:22:04 AM 
Event time (UTC): 4/8/2014 8:22:04 AM 
Event ID: a1d9a08b129642d8afd284051089ca09 
Event sequence: 1394 
Event occurrence: 4 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/280/ROOT-1-130414157749022422 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\HostingSpaces\sceryeme\sceryemen.com\wwwroot\ 
    Machine name: ACCU17 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 23016 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: ACCU17\sceryemencom_web 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://sceryemen.com/assets/js/flexdropdown.jsbin/getcdndnsAAT2g62JNXAW3zxZ&video_id=LDrkWJpO2XA 
    Request path: /assets/js/flexdropdown.jsbin/getcdndnsAAT2g62JNXAW3zxZ&video_id=LDrkWJpO2XA 
    User host address: 50.57.104.33 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: ACCU17\sceryemencom_web 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 27 
    Thread account name: ACCU17\sceryemencom_web 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


Custom event details: Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32768">1309</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>3</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-04-08T08:22:04.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1448969</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Accu17.denver.wehostwebsites.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>3005</Data>
    <Data>An unhandled exception has occurred.</Data>
    <Data>4/8/2014 2:22:04 AM</Data>
    <Data>4/8/2014 8:22:04 AM</Data>
    <Data>a1d9a08b129642d8afd284051089ca09</Data>
    <Data>1394</Data>
    <Data>4</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>/LM/W3SVC/280/ROOT-1-130414157749022422</Data>
    <Data>Full</Data>
    <Data>/</Data>
    <Data>C:\HostingSpaces\sceryeme\sceryemen.com\wwwroot\</Data>
    <Data>ACCU17</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>23016</Data>
    <Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
    <Data>ACCU17\sceryemencom_web</Data>
    <Data>HttpException</Data>
    <Data>A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&amp;).
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)

</Data>
    <Data>http://sceryemen.com/assets/js/flexdropdown.jsbin/getcdndnsAAT2g62JNXAW3zxZ&amp;video_id=LDrkWJpO2XA</Data>
    <Data>/assets/js/flexdropdown.jsbin/getcdndnsAAT2g62JNXAW3zxZ&amp;video_id=LDrkWJpO2XA</Data>
    <Data>50.57.104.33</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>False</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>ACCU17\sceryemencom_web</Data>
    <Data>27</Data>
    <Data>ACCU17\sceryemencom_web</Data>
    <Data>False</Data>
    <Data>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Do you expect the URL 'http://sceryemen.com/assets/js/flexdropdown.jsbin/getcdndnsAAT2g62JNXAW3zxZ&video_id=LDrkWJpO2X' to be requested? Because the Exception message is 'Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).' and that's the URL.

Comment: I have JavaScript file "sceryemen.com/assets/js/flexdropdown.js" but it look that someone trying to add  "bin/getcdndnsAAT2g62JNXAW3zxZ&video_id=LDrkWJpO2XA" to the url!!!!

Comment: I'm WILDLY guessing -- the "getcdndns" part of that unexpected URL seems to suggest that a Content Delivery Network (CDN) is being referenced or added. Check with service provider to see if they enabled CDN (with or without you knowing). Also, perhaps malware on the shared server is adding this to the URL (unlikely, but possible).

Answer (score 3):

A simple method that doesn't involve code changes would be to turn Rapid Fail Protection off on the application pool that is hosting this application.  IIS defaults the maximum failure rate for 30 minutes to 30.  After that, your application pool gets shut down and you get the 503.  Turning off Rapid Fail Protection will at least get you beyond your application from killing the process.